# Orthonormal Basis in $L^2[0,5/8]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, wavelets

It is well-known that the Haar wavelet system forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,1]$. I am interested in forming a similar orthonormal basis for $L^2[0,\frac58]$. We write $[0, \frac58] = [0,\frac12] \cup [\frac12, \frac58]$ and let $e_1 = \frac{1_{[0,1/2]}}{\|1_{[0,1/2]}\|}$ and $e_2 = \frac{1_{[1/2,5/8]}}{\|1_{[1/2,5/8]}\|}$. Since $\frac58$ is a dyadic rational the support of some of the Haar wavelets are contained in $[0, \frac58]$. I am interested to know whether $e_1$ and $e_2$ along with the Haar wavelets whose support is contained in $[0,\frac58]$ forms an orthonormal basis.

With some computations we can easily get that this sequence of wavelets is at the minimum orthonormal. To show that its closed span is dense I am trying to argue that if there is $f \in L^2[0,\frac58]$ such that $f \perp \{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, then $f = 0$ a.e. Any help is welcomed!

Comment: To me it seems easier to argue this way: let $f \in L^2[0, \tfrac 58]$. You want to show that $f$ can be approximated to within $\epsilon$ by sums of restricted Haar wavelets. Extend $f$ to $\hat f \in L^2[0, 1]$ by setting it to $0$ on the new inputs. We know $\hat f$ can be approximated by sums of Haar wavelets - can you extract an approximation for $f$ from this approximation for $\hat f$? (being a little careful about what happens with $e_1$ and $e_2$ and the intervals $[\tfrac 12, \tfrac 34]$, $[\tfrac 12, 1]$, and $[0, 1]$)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: I do not see how to extract the approximation in this case. Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: OK... Writing $\psi_{n,k}$ for the Haar wavelets, say we have a finite sum $\sum \lambda_{n, k} \psi_{n, k}$ which is within $\epsilon$ of $g \in L^2[0, 1]$. Can you argue that $\sum \lambda_{n, k} \psi_{n, k}|_{[0, \frac 58]}$ is within $\epsilon$ of $g|_{[0, \frac 58]}$?